# Symfony 4. Авторизация через LDAP. Как подключить кастомный AuthenticationProvider?

Tags: php, ldap, symfony4, аутентификация

Корень зла в том, что мой LDAP сервер куда я стучусь авторизовывает исключительно по dn полученным из сущности (Entry) после поиска.
То есть ищет по username:

```
$query: (samAccountName=AIvanov)
```

а вот авторизовывает только по строке dn:

```
$dn: CN=Иванов Алексей Иванович,OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=company,DC=local
```

И если есть путь как с помощью конфигов указать способ передать из кастомного UserProvider в родной LdapBindAuthenticationProvider инфу о том что нужно использовать не username из токена а взять username из объекта этого кастомного юзера

```
$user->getUsername()
```

который и вернет это чертово ФИО, я буду благодарен. 
Потому что иначе только создание своего кастомного CustomLdapBindAuthenticationProvider с чем я сюда и пришел.

Использовал методичку: http://symfony.ru/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

И остановился на том что не знаю какая связь между своей фабрикой и фаерволом и имею ошибку при вызове этой свое фабрики.

Итак, следуя методички создал кастомный провайдер аутентификации. Попытался отнаследоваться от родного Ldap... но у него свойство ldap приватное, поэтому просто скопировал весь Ldap... к себе и переназвал его в CustomLdapBindAuthenticationProvider. Изменил там эту одну строку из-за которой весь сыр-бор. 
Далее создал свою фабрику отнаследовав ее от родной FormLoginLdapFactory

```
class CustomFormLoginLdapFactory extends FormLoginLdapFactory {
protected function createAuthProvider(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProviderId)
{
    $provider = 'security.authentication.provider.ldap_bind.'.$id;
    $definition = $container
        //->setDefinition($provider, new ChildDefinition('security.authentication.provider.ldap_bind'))
        ->setDefinition($provider, new ChildDefinition(CustomLdapBindAuthenticationProvider::class))
        ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProviderId))
        ->replaceArgument(1, new Reference('security.user_checker.'.$id))
        ->replaceArgument(2, $id)
        ->replaceArgument(3, new Reference($config['service']))
        ->replaceArgument(4, $config['dn_string'])
    ;
    if (!empty($config['query_string'])) {
        $definition->addMethodCall('setQueryString', [$config['query_string']]);
    }

    return $provider;
}
```

}

Подключил как указано в методичке сервис

```
App\Security\Authentication\Provider\CustomLdapBindAuthenticationProvider:
    arguments:
        $userProvider: '@Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface'
        $ldap: '@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap'
        $dnString: '{username}'
```

и так тоже пытался (у меня именно объект ChainUserProvider передается в первый аргумент)

```
App\Security\Authentication\Provider\CustomLdapBindAuthenticationProvider:
    arguments:
        $userProvider: '@Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\ChainUserProvider'
        $ldap: '@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap'
        $dnString: '{username}'
```

И наконец в ядро (src/Kernel.php) воткнул новый метод, тоже из методички взял:

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $extension = $container->getExtension('security');
    $extension->addSecurityListenerFactory(new CustomFormLoginLdapFactory());
}
```

а вот что писать в блоке firewalls - не очевидно для меня и в методичке нет указаний в итоге оригинальное не работает. попытка подменить form_login_ldap на что-то кастомное аналогичное, типа custom_form_login_ldap не увенчалась успехом, симфони говорит что может быть только оригинальное имя в этой части конфига.

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        provider: chain_provider
        #http_basic: ~
        form_login_ldap:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            service: 'Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap'
            dn_string: 'cn={username},OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=company,DC=local'
```

когда запускаю с таким конфигом:

Service "security.authentication.provider.ldap_bind.main": The argument "0" doesn't exist.
(1/1) OutOfBoundsException

Service "security.authentication.provider.ldap_bind.main": The argument "0" doesn't exist.
in Definition.php line 275
at Definition->replaceArgument(0, object(Reference))in ResolveChildDefinitionsPass.php line 163
at ResolveChildDefinitionsPass->doResolveDefinition(object(ChildDefinition))in ResolveChildDefinitionsPass.php line 62
at ResolveChildDefinitionsPass->resolveDefinition(object(ChildDefinition))in ResolveChildDefinitionsPass.php line 43
at ResolveChildDefinitionsPass->processValue(object(ChildDefinition), true)in AbstractRecursivePass.php line 82

Итак, как связать фабрику с секцией firewalls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

с помощью телеграмм канала и пользователя artem проблема была решена.
Итак первое, как связать фабрику с секцией firewall:
тут все довольно очевидно и быстро нашлось, невнимательность породила этот вопрос, на может кто будет гуглить что бы вопрос не остался без ответа

фабричный метод

```
public function getKey()
{
    return 'form-login-ldap';
}
```

устанавливает ключ для секции в firewall: form_login_ldap
Только тире превращаются в подчеркивания.

Ну и самое главное, как заставить подключаться CustomLdapBindAuthenticationProvider.
Оригинальная фабрика, откуда я брал код под копирку FormLoginLdapFactory использует в качестве ключей цифры. И у нее это работает видимо потому, что где в глубинах вендорных конфигов симфони описание сервиса LdapBindAuthenticationProvider использует эти самые цифры для обозначения аргументов:

```
->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProviderId))
->replaceArgument(1, new Reference('security.user_checker.'.$id))
->replaceArgument(2, $id)
->replaceArgument(3, new Reference($config['service']))
->replaceArgument(4, $config['dn_string'])
```

Я же, подключая свой CustomLdapBindAuthenticationProvider, в конфиге сервисов указываю:

```
App\Security\Authentication\Provider\CustomLdapBindAuthenticationProvider:
    arguments:
        $userProvider: '@Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface'
        $userChecker: '@Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface'
        $providerKey: ''
        $ldap: '@Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap'
        $dnString: '{username}'
        $userRepository: '@App\Repository\UserRepository'
```

и поэтому должен так же указать и в фабрике:

```
->setDefinition($provider, new ChildDefinition(CustomLdapBindAuthenticationProvider::class))
->replaceArgument('$userProvider', new Reference($userProviderId))
->replaceArgument('$userChecker', new Reference('security.user_checker.'.$id))
->replaceArgument('$providerKey', $id)
->replaceArgument('$ldap', new Reference($config['service']))
->replaceArgument('$dnString', $config['dn_string'])
```

И все заработало.